# Showmessage on top of a modal form

Tags: forms, delphi, dialog, modal-dialog

With the code bellow, when I call `MessageDlg`, the modal form disappears.
How to avoid?

```
...     
LoginForm_Create; //FfrmLoginForm created here
try
  if FfrmLoginForm.ShowModal = mrOk then 
  begin
    Fuser := db_authuser( FfrmLoginForm.edtUserName.Text, FfrmLoginForm.edtPassword.text ); 
  if Fuser <> nil then 
    result := 1
  else begin
    MessageDlg('Username or password invalid', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    result := -2;
  end;
end else //mrCancel
  result := -1;
finally
  LoginForm_Close; // << FfrmLoginForm.Release;
end;
...
```

Comment: That is because the rest of your code is executed *after* ShowModal. What you should do is put that authentication code e.g. in your FfrmLoginForm.OnShow() handler. You can then set ModalResult to signal success or failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form is closed when `ShowModal` returns. Hence the behaviour that you observe.

If you wish your dialog to show on top of the modal form, you need to show it before `ShowModal` returns. Do that by moving the `mrOK` code into whichever code on your modal form sets `ModalResult` to `mrOK`.